# How do I use ReplayKit's class RPBroadcastActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, live, broadcast, replaykit

I want to present RPBroadcastActivityViewController, but fail. The sample code just present a black view.

```
- (IBAction)displayServiceViewController:(id)sender {
    RPBroadcastActivityViewController *rpBroadcastActivityViewController = [[RPBroadcastActivityViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:rpBroadcastActivityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I hope it's the following effect:

[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lVvP.png)

Comment: already solved:

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)displayServiceViewController:(id)sender {
    [RPBroadcastActivityViewController loadBroadcastActivityViewControllerWithHandler:^(RPBroadcastActivityViewController * _Nullable broadcastActivityViewController, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        broadcastActivityViewController.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:broadcastActivityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];

}
```